# Follow a constantly varying input signal with a PID Controller

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I got a TF of my plant `G(s) = s + 10/3s^3 + 8s^2 + 30s + 25` and I would like to implement a PID controller so that the system closely follows the varying input signal, I used `r(t) = 0.5sin(t) + 0.5`. How can I calculate the correct setting for Kp, Ki and Kd to do this without guessing random values?

I made this feedbackloop in simulink
[image: feedbackloop]

And I want an output signal that follows the input signal, so the yellow and blue line should lie on eachother.
[image: output signal]